# Does bit-shifting properly isolate bytes on different endian systems?

Tags: c, endianness

I'm attempting to write an integer to a byte buffer. Will the following code always write in big endian format, regardless of the endianness of the system:

```
byte[0] = (uint8_t) (val & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
byte[1] = (uint8_t) (val & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
byte[2] = (uint8_t) (val & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
byte[3] = (uint8_t) (val & 0x000000FF);
```

Unfortunately, I don't have access to htonl() and similar functions.

Comment: There is no need for masking, presuming `val` is at least `uint32_t` (and smaller makes no sense).

Comment: FYI, most of the time there's a `#define` for the system endianness (e.g. `BIG_ENDIAN`, `LITTLE_ENDIAN`) as well as some `bswap` intrinsic.

Comment: neither there's need for masking nor for casting, as the result array is supposed to be in `unit8_t` cells.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this will work correctly. The bit-shifting operators deal with the abstract numeric values, not the way they're represented in the hardware registers or RAM. `>> N` is essentially equivalent to dividing by 2<sup>N</sup>.